# How can I disable CONFIG_PM when building Linux kernel for x86_64

Tags: linux, kernel, config, power-management

I've unselected all options in the "Power Management and ACPI options" submenu,

[image]
But options `CONFIG_PM`, `CONFIG_PM_SLEEP` are still enabled,

```
# Power management and ACPI options
#
# CONFIG_SUSPEND is not set
CONFIG_HIBERNATE_CALLBACKS=y
# CONFIG_HIBERNATION is not set
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP=y
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP_SMP=y
# CONFIG_PM_AUTOSLEEP is not set
# CONFIG_PM_WAKELOCKS is not set
CONFIG_PM=y
# CONFIG_PM_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_PM_CLK=y
CONFIG_PM_GENERIC_DOMAINS=y
# CONFIG_WQ_POWER_EFFICIENT_DEFAULT is not set
CONFIG_PM_GENERIC_DOMAINS_SLEEP=y
CONFIG_PM_GENERIC_DOMAINS_OF=y
# CONFIG_ENERGY_MODEL is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_ACPI=y
# CONFIG_ACPI is not set
CONFIG_X86_PM_TIMER=y
```

And manually editing `.config` to change all options to "is not set" didn't work either. After running "make", these options would be enabled automatically. How can I disable `CONFIG_PM` and `CONFIG_PM_SLEEP`?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following from the top level of my kernel source:

```
find . -name Kconfig -exec grep -H 'select PM$' {} \;
```

which, unless you are running on arm/mach, finds only kernel/power/Kconfig.  PM will be forced on only if you turn on PM_SLEEP.  Otherwise, turning off PM turns off all power management.

Edit:  Note that PM_SLEEP has "def_bool y"  This means that unless explicitly set, it will be turned on.  To turn it off, change .config to:

```
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP=n
```

Note that this means the developers are pretty sure they want this on all the time, so the code isn't being tested with it off.  You will be on your own to find and fix bugs that may result from turning it off.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But I can't find a way to turn off PM_SLEEP. Chaing "CONFIG_PM_SLEEP=y" to "#CONFIG_PM_SLEEP is not set" won't work. Somehow it'll be enabled automatically. And there is no option that select PM_SLEEP because `$ find . -name Kconfig -exec grep -H 'select PM_SLEEP' {} \; ` returns empty result.

Comment: I hadn't seen def_bool before.  Just added it to the answer.

Comment: Ah, def_bool is what's wrong. But `PM_SLEEP=n` didn't work. I know "#CONFIG_PM_SLEEP is not set" is supposed to unset a option but somehow it didn't work. Eventually I disabled `CONFIG_PM` by changing "def_bool y" to `"def_bool n" in kernel/power/Kconfig.

Comment: looks like you would like changing system ACPI PM default. I think you can dynamic insert SSDT to reach it.

Comment: @TerenceLiu Are you suggesting that I can insert SSDT to disable power management? Actually I'm trying to use PM macros to replace "ifdef CONFIG_PM_SLEEP" and want to know if there is no compiling issue if I disable PM_SLEEP. Thank you anyway!